# Сбой при распаковке win-rar

Tags: winrar, eclipse

Win rar при распаковке eclipse ругается на то, что имена каких-то файлов превышают длину в 260 символов. Вопрос; как это решить?
Eclipse juno, который был скачан 3 минуты назад.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total Commander, через него распаковывай. По крайней мере у меня получилось таким образом решить аналогичную проблему